# Is there a way to convert an input Matrix to an ArrayList of ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, arraylist

Here is an example input that I want to make an ArrayList of ArrayLists:

```
1,0,1
1,1,1
0,0,1
```

I have `Scanner in` that holds the input and I was thinking of having a for-loop to add the numbers to the ArrayList of ArrayLists using `in.nextInt()`. But the problem is how do I find when I should move on to the next ArrayList within the big ArrayList?

Comment: int xAxisLength = 2;
int yAxisLength = 2;
int zAxisLength = 2; 
ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> space = new ArrayList<>(xAxisLength);


for (int i = 0; i < xAxisLength; i++) {
    space.add(new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(yAxisLength));
    for (int j = 0; j < yAxisLength; j++) {
        space.get(i).add(new ArrayList<String>(zAxisLength));
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

You could either define an arbitrary limit of numbers before moving to the next ArrayList

```java
while (condition to keep reading)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < arbitrarylimit; i++) {
   List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   // read the input 
   biglist.add(list);
 }
}
```

Or you could establish that if you find a new line before a number then it should be inserted into a new ArrayList.

```java
while (condition to keep reading)
{
   List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   String result = scanner.nextLine();
   // split result and add it to a list
   biglist.add(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

- read in each row as a single line
- Each number can be separated by commas and or spaces
- Use a stream and split them on the commas and spaces 
  converting them to a `List<Integer>`
- Then add that list to the overall list of lists.

```
String line = "";
List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
// take input until a `#` is typed on a new line.
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    List<Integer> nums = Arrays.stream(line.split("[\\s,]+"))
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    lists.add(nums);
}
lists.forEach(System.out::println);
```

For the following input per line

```
1 0,1
1,1,1
0 0 1
```

You get the following output

```
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: What if I don't want a "#" in the input?

Comment: You can use any character or string.  The input only signals the end of input and isn't used elsewhere.  You can also prompt for the number of rows and columns. And use those.  But if your entering this from a console you need to signal end of input.  Sometimes, depending on the OS, a ctrl character may be used.  How would you want to do it?